# How to solve $\sum_{k=2}^\infty {\frac{1}{k^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm using the integral test to determine if this series converges. From what I have so far it seems that it diverges, but according to wolfram alpha it converges. Where is my mistake?

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty {\frac{1}{k^2-1}} \to \int_{2}^M \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$$

$$\int_{2}^M \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\ln|M-1|-\ln|M+1|+\ln|3|\Big)$$

$$ \lim_{M\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\Big(\ln|M-1|-\ln|M+1|+\ln|3|\Big)$$

Comment: What did you edit?

Comment: @air: I added some relevant tags and changed
$$ln$$
(note the slant) to the correct function name
$$\ln$$
(this is typed as `\ln`, as opposed to `ln`). Typing `ln` is incorrect because what's to distinguish that from the product of two variables named `l` and `n`? A function name is generally written upright to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\dfrac1{k^2-1} = \dfrac12 \left(\dfrac1{k-1} - \dfrac1{k+1} \right)$$ Write out some terms and you can notice some nice cancelling going on.

---

If you want to stick to your integral test, then note that $\ln(M-1) - \ln(M+1) = \ln \left(\dfrac{M-1}{M+1}\right)$ which tends to $\ln(1) = 0$ for large $M$.

Comment: How does $\dfrac{M-1}{M+1}$ tends to $\ln(1) = 0$ for large $M$?

Comment: @air_wizardo $\dfrac{M-1}{M+1} \to 1$ as $M$ gets large and since $\ln$ is a continuous function, we have $\ln \left(\dfrac{M-1}{M+1}\right) \to \ln(1) = 0$

Comment: But why $\dfrac{M-1}{M+1} \to 1$ as $M$ gets large? Can you explain how you got that?

Comment: @air_wizardo $$\dfrac{M-1}{M+1} = \dfrac{M+1-2}{M+1} = 1 - \dfrac2{M+1}$$ Can you see now that $\dfrac2{M+1} \to 0$ as $M$ increases? This would immediately imply that $1 - \dfrac2{M+1} \to 1$, i.e. $\dfrac{M-1}{M+1} \to 1$.

Comment: It behaves like $\frac{M}{M}$ by looking at dominating terms. Hence  the limit tends to $1.$

Comment: @Marvis: That's some nice manipulation there. Now I can see why it goes to 1. Thanks.

Comment: @air_wizardo Marvis's manipulation provides the formal explanation, but you should get used to 'seeing' that the dominating terms are the same and so it has to go to 1, as in Joe's comment.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify that last expression:

$$\ln|M-1|-\ln|M+1|=\ln\left|\frac{M-1}{M+1}\right|=\ln\left|1-\frac2{M+1}\right|\to 0$$ as $M\to\infty$. (Actually, you can evaluate the sum exactly, since the series is two intermeshed telescoping series.)

Answer (score 2):

The integral test, used directly, works, if one can evaluate the limit. However, many functions are either very difficult to integrate, or have an integral that cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

So the first step probably should have been a simplification. Note that for $k\ge 2$, we have $k^2-1\gt \frac{k^2}{2}$, and therefore 
$$0\lt \dfrac{1}{k^2-1}\lt \dfrac{2}{k^2}.$$
Now you probably know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ converges, so by comparison our series does.

If one doesn't know that (unlikely at this stage), the integral test can be used on $\displaystyle \sum_2^\infty \dfrac{2}{k^2}$.

Comment: Where is the mistake?

Comment: @air_wizardo: Apologies, no mistake. Just incomplete. Will fix my answer.